# Farseer Physics Tutorials, Help files

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-3.5, farseer

Is there a tutotial or help file, suitable for a beginner c# programmer to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary documentation for the Farseer Physics engine is on the homepage.

http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Documentation&referringTitle=Home

You can also check out the source code, they have a demos folder in there, though it's only got one example, but it can show you how to implement the engine

http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics/SourceControl/DirectoryView.aspx?SourcePath=%24%2fFarseerPhysics%2fDemos%2fXNA3%2fGettingStarted&changeSetId=40048

For a last resort, check out their forums, and ask some questions. They seem nice enough that they should be able to help you out with any questions.

http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics/Thread/List.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question, but for future searchers I will post a few links:

**Farseer Physics Helper**

Physics helper for Blend makes it very easy to create realistic looking games or demos using practically no code :)

http://physicshelper.codeplex.com/

**Farseer Physics Engine Simple Samples**

Very simple and easy to understand samples (compared to the original Farseer ones)

http://farseersimplesamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Andy Beaulieu has beein doing a lot of work to make Farseer easier to use in Silverlight, you can read about it here:

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/115/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Great webcast with a Farseer tutorial - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh781459.aspx